# how to display video from database path in php?

Tags: php, mysql, video

I am having a mysql table holding video file name. Videos are stored in a different sub-directory. I tried  tag for displaying the video on my web page. But it doesn't work. I tried giving the file name directly in the code and the video plays fine.

Please help me out.
here is the code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="video/<? '.$row_dis[video_path].' ?>" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide more information, e.g. the subdirectory of your videos, the print_r of $row_dis and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to be sure about the nature of the problem. At first glance, there can be a problem with relative paths and short php tags you used in source element. Can you test this code like this:

```
<source src="/path/to/video/<?php echo $row_dis[video_path]; ?>" type="video/mp4">
```

Additionally, you can provide the source code of the page generated with this code and compare it with directly given file name to make things perfectly clear.